# Changing the default layout produced by algorithm and algorithmic packages

Tags: table-of-contents, numbering, captions, algorithms

If the default output of the `algorithm` and `algorithmic` packages for the following code:

```
\begin{algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\PRINT \texttt{‘‘Hello, World!’’}    
\end{algorithmic}
\caption{Pseudocode of visualRSS's polling algorithm.}
\label{PseudocodevRSSPollingAlgorithm.}
\end{algorithm}
```

Is:

[image]

Can this be changed so that the lines are removed and a caption be centrally displayed under the pseudocode such as:

`Algorithm 4.3: Printing HelloWorld.`

So that an algorithm is referenced by chapter number and then its number within that chapter, and that this format is also present in a `List of Algorithms` at the beginning of a document?

Thanks to the answer given below, I have been able to largely achieve what I want. But I notice that I can use the \print and \State instructions but if I try to use a \FOR like this:

```
\setcounter{algorithm}{0}
\begin{algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]            
\State $pollingDateTime \leftarrow now - 1 hour$
\FOR{\texttt{each} $rssFeed$}
\print \texttt{‘‘Hello, World!’’}
\ENDFOR   
\end{algorithmic}    
\caption{Algorithm 1.}        
\end{algorithm}
```

That this ends in a LaTeX `Undefined control sequence.` error. What can be done about this?

Thanks

Mr Morgan.

Comment: The [`algorithms` bundle](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms) provides `\STATE`, while [`algorithmicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx) provides `\State`. If you wish to use `algorithmicx` with the older `algorithms` syntax, you need to load `\usepackage{algcompatible}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, of course!

The main idea is to restyle the `algorithm` float construction. Since `algorithm` loads the [`float` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/float), you can easily define your own float construction, say `newruled`:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\fs@newruled{\def\@fs@cfont{\bfseries}\let\@fs@capt\floatc@plain% Caption style
  \def\@fs@pre{\hrule height.8pt depth0pt \kern2pt}% Line at top of algorithm + 2pt gap
  \def\@fs@post{}%\def\@fs@post{\kern2pt\hrule\relax}% Remove line below `\caption`
  \def\@fs@mid{\kern2pt\hrule\kern2pt}% Line at bottom of algorithm
  \let\@fs@iftopcapt\iffalse}% Place caption at bottom
\makeatother
\floatstyle{newruled}
\restylefloat{algorithm}
```

The 6 components of the float is defined within a `\fs@<style>` macro, which is called when you use `\floatstyle{<style>}`:

- `\@fs@cfont` defines the caption label font;
- `\@fs@capt` defines the way the caption is handled. `float` already defines a number of these (including `plain`, which I've used);
- `\@fs@pre` specifies whatever is `pre`cedes (or is printed *before*) your algorithm;
- `\@fs@post` specifies whatever is at the `post`erior` of (or printed *after*) your algorithm float. In the regular setup, with a caption below a float, this macro comes after the caption;
- `\@fs@mid` is inserted above the caption and below the algorithm;
- `\@fs@iftopcapt` is a conditional for setting the caption at the top or at the bottom of the algorithm. If it's set to `\iftrue`, then the caption will be set at the top, otherwise (if set to `\iffalse`) the caption will end up at the bottom of the algorithm.

For adjusting the counter representation, the usual things are at play:

```
\renewcommand{\thealgorithm}{\thechapter.\arabic{algorithm}}
\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{algorithm}{chapter}
\makeatother
```

We first adjust `\thealgorithm` to include `\thechapter.`, and also reset the `algorithm` counter with every change in the `chapter` counter (using `\@addtoreset`).

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\fs@newruled{\def\@fs@cfont{\bfseries}\let\@fs@capt\floatc@plain% Caption style
  \def\@fs@pre{\hrule height.8pt depth0pt \kern2pt}% Line at top of algorithm + 2pt gap
  \def\@fs@post{}%\def\@fs@post{\kern2pt\hrule\relax}% Remove line below `\caption`
  \def\@fs@mid{\kern2pt\hrule\kern2pt}% Line at bottom of algorithm
  \let\@fs@iftopcapt\iffalse}% Place caption at bottom
\makeatother
\floatstyle{newruled}
\restylefloat{algorithm}

\algnewcommand{\print}{\State \textbf{print} }
\renewcommand{\thealgorithm}{\thechapter.\arabic{algorithm}}
\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{algorithm}{chapter}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listofalgorithms
\setcounter{chapter}{3}% Just for this example

\chapter{A chapter}

\setcounter{algorithm}{2}% Just for this example
\begin{algorithm}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \print \texttt{``Hello World!''}
  \end{algorithmic}
  \caption{Printing HelloWorld}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Above I've used `algpseudocode` from the [`algorithmicx` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx), although you can stick to `algorithmic` (provided by the [`algorithms` bundle](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms).

Answer (score 0):

An *addendum* to @Werner's answer:

For the numbering, it is enough to load the `algorithm` package with option `chapter`. On another hand, it accepts a number of commands from the `caption` package, in particular those pertaining to fonts and alignment — not skip.

Here is an example with the `boxed` style and a left-aligned caption:

```
\documentclass[12pt,leqno]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fourier}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[fleqn]{mathtools}%
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionFont{red}{\color{red}}
\captionsetup[algorithm]{font = small, labelfont = {sc, red}, singlelinecheck = off}
\usepackage[boxed, section]{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{section}{3}
\begin{algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\PRINT \texttt{‘‘Hello, World!’’}
\end{algorithmic}
\caption{Pseudocode of visualRSS's polling algorithm.}
\label{PseudocodevRSSPollingAlgorithm.}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]